# App crashes on tap on button iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uibutton, exc-bad-access

I know that this is a quiet famous question and in fact feeling awkward while posting this question on SO.

But still I am trapped so I have no other options.

I am trying to create a Bingo Game and everything was going great. Suddenly my app is crashing on tap on a UIButton. Here is my simple code:

```
-(IBAction)buttontapped:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender ;
    CGRect frame =  btn.frame;
    int cardNumber = 0;
    if(frame.origin.x > self.firstCard.frame.origin.x && frame.origin.x < self.secondCard.frame.origin.x){
        //First card
        cardNumber = 1;
    }else {
        //Second card
        cardNumber = 2;
    }
    int cardTitle = (int)[btn.titleLabel.text integerValue];
    BOOL btnPresed = NO;
    if(cardTitle != 0){
        btnPresed =  [self.delegate numberPressedAtIndexPath:self.indexPath boxNumber:cardTitle cardNumber:cardNumber];
    }
}
```

Here are the screenshots of my log:

[image]

[image]

Now according to log, nothing is `nil`, not even the `delegate`. 
I am not getting any reason for crash as well. 
So where I might be wrong.

Comment: Check attributes (strong / assign / weak) of your properties `self.delegate` and `self.indexPath`. Chance is you don't have them retained.

Comment: well, my delegate is strong one and indexPath is assign.

Comment: There is your problem, `indexPath` should be strong

Comment: Unfortunately or fortunately, turning indexPath to strong, did the trick. But I am still surprised that it was working fine 30 minutes ago.

Comment: Your delegate should be assign and indexPath must be strong